# Heat map of portion of the sky visible for a given observatory on Earth?

Tags: observational-astronomy, mathematics, sky-survey

Reading [Calculating area of visible sky](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8451/calculating-area-of-visible-sky) I started wondering **which portion of the sky one could observe how long given the 3D coordinates of an observatory, and two points in time**.

In other words, I would love to have a formula $f(\lambda,\varphi,h,t_1,t_2, \delta, \alpha)$ for an observatory at $(\lambda, \varphi, h)$ with longitude $\lambda$, latitude $\varphi$, height $h$ above the [geoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid) which shows how many hours between time $t_1$ and $t_2$ which point $(\alpha, \delta)$ of the sky is visible. Here, $\alpha$ is the right ascension and $\delta$ the declination. I am sure this calculation has been done before, and I am simply missing the search terms.

For convencience, let us assume the reference frame to be the usual [WGS84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System). Let's further assume, that our observatory is on a hill on an otherwise flat landscape, so that we that we do not have to worry about skyline or mountains concealing our view to the sky.

#### References

- [ESO's object visibility calculator](https://www.eso.org/sci/observing/tools/calendar/observability.html)

#### Related

- [Throughout the year, are all parts of the night sky visible from any given point on Earth?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/27732/throughout-the-year-are-all-parts-of-the-night-sky-visible-from-any-given-point)

Comment: Here's the [WGS84 ellipsoid equations](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27194/12102) at least